# Streaming Webcam from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04 via WSL2 and usbip

Tags: webcam, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ffmpeg, xrdp

**Background**
Alright so I was able to set up my Windows 10 desktop with WSL2 in order to run Ubuntu 18.04. I'm trying to get the webcam to be accessible and have picked and pieced together the following tutorials in order to get myself to where I am.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IL7Jd9rjgrM
- https://github.com/rpasek/usbip-wsl2-instructions
- https://www.davecorder.org/windows-10/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/gcbjfi/module_usbcore_not_found_in_directory/
- https://dmaiorino.com/?p=12

**The Why** 
"Why would you go through this painstaking effort? Seems dumb." you might be telling yourself. Well I think that it's dumb that WSL2 doesn't have a USB pass-through, so there's that. But I develop on Windows traditionally, and with a recent computer vision project I'm undertaking that incorporates the Nvidia Isaac SDK (only available on Ubuntu 18.04) I was hoping to continue to use Windows to develop, and then Ubuntu 18.04 to test. I'm trying to stay away from dual booting because switching back and forth between OSs is time-consuming.

**Current State**
What I'm able to do is pass through the web camera using usbip from windows using the following commands
`.\usbip.exe bind -b 1-189`
`.\usbipd.exe -d -4`

and then on the linux side I connect it by running 
`sudo usbip attach --remote=172.30.64.1 --busid=1-220`
except that I put in my own remote address and busid

What that results in is the ability to see that the camera is attached and seen by linux, but no matter what program/library I use, none of them are able to open the webcam

Here are some outputs from different commands people have used to display camera information:

```
~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices 
Logitech Webcam C930e (usb-vhci_hcd.0-1):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1

~$ v4l-info /dev/video0

### v4l2 device info [/dev/video0] ###
general info
    VIDIOC_QUERYCAP
    driver                  : "uvcvideo"
    card                    : "Logitech Webcam C930e"
    bus_info                : "usb-vhci_hcd.0-1"
    version                 : 4.19.84
    capabilities            : 0x84a00001 [VIDEO_CAPTURE,?,?,STREAMING,(null)]

standards

inputs
    VIDIOC_ENUMINPUT(0)
    index                   : 0
    name                    : "Camera 1"
    type                    : CAMERA
    audioset                : 0
    tuner                   : 0
    std                     : 0x0 []
    status                  : 0x0 []

video capture
    VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT(0,VIDEO_CAPTURE)
    index                   : 0
    type                    : VIDEO_CAPTURE
    flags                   : 0
    description             : "YUYV 4:2:2"
    pixelformat             : 0x56595559 [YUYV]
    VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT(1,VIDEO_CAPTURE)
    index                   : 1
    type                    : VIDEO_CAPTURE
    flags                   : 1
    description             : "Motion-JPEG"
    pixelformat             : 0x47504a4d [MJPG]
    VIDIOC_G_FMT(VIDEO_CAPTURE)
    type                    : VIDEO_CAPTURE
    fmt.pix.width           : 640
    fmt.pix.height          : 480
    fmt.pix.pixelformat     : 0x56595559 [YUYV]
    fmt.pix.field           : NONE
    fmt.pix.bytesperline    : 1280
    fmt.pix.sizeimage       : 614400
    fmt.pix.colorspace      : SRGB
    fmt.pix.priv            : 4276996862

controls
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+0)
    id                      : 9963776
    type                    : INTEGER
    name                    : "Brightness"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 255
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 128
    flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+1)
    id                      : 9963777
    type                    : INTEGER
    name                    : "Contrast"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 255
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 128
    flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+2)
    id                      : 9963778
    type                    : INTEGER
    name                    : "Saturation"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 255
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 128
    flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+12)
    id                      : 9963788
    type                    : BOOLEAN
    name                    : "White Balance Temperature, Auto"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 1
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 1
    flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+19)
    id                      : 9963795
    type                    : INTEGER
    name                    : "Gain"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 255
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 0
    flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+24)
    id                      : 9963800
    type                    : MENU
    name                    : "Power Line Frequency"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 2
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 2
    flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+26)
    id                      : 9963802
    type                    : INTEGER
    name                    : "White Balance Temperature"
    minimum                 : 2000
    maximum                 : 7500
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 4000
    flags                   : INACTIVE
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+27)
    id                      : 9963803
    type                    : INTEGER
    name                    : "Sharpness"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 255
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 128
    flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+28)
    id                      : 9963804
    type                    : INTEGER
    name                    : "Backlight Compensation"
    minimum                 : 0
    maximum                 : 1
    step                    : 1
    default_value           : 0
    flags                   : unknown

~$ sudo ffmpeg -y -t 5 -f video4linux2  -i /dev/video0  out.mov
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
/dev/video0: Input/output error

~$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -frames 1 out.jpg
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
/dev/video0: Input/output error
```

I'm not sure if I don't have a specific library, driver, random other thing, but everything I've tried so far seems to not solve the problem. 
**Question**
Linux sees the web camera, knows that it is a web camera, but is not processing the camera feed. What would you recommend I do to be able to process the video feed? I think this is an issue with my settings when I originally set up linux with `menuconfig`.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: a tragedy that this is unanswered after all this time. Did you ever get a solution? I need to talk to a webcam over WSL

Comment: I'm sorry, but no... ended up just biting the bullet and getting a dedicated machine to develop the project on with ubuntu 18.04